# How to initialize static member array in class with template

Tags: c++, templates, static-members

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Test
{
    union obj
    {
        union obj* next;
        int num;
    };

    static const int SZ=3;
    static obj* volatile list[SZ];
};

template <class T>
Test<T>::obj* volatile
Test<T>::list[SZ]=
{
    0, 0, 0
};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

With g++, the error I get is:

```
18|error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '*' token
```

Comment: does adding `typename` before `Test<T>::obj*` helps?

Comment: Does it work if you declare that union outside of the class?

Comment: Both are ok,but I just know the latter.

Comment: Closing this question is unjustified and unhelpful. Two questions may have the same answer but not be a duplicate. I was searching for how to initialize a static array of a templated class. The apparent duplicate question somewhat assumes I already knew the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the keyword typename before `Test<T>::obj*` in the definition of the member.

Comment: @Potatoswatter I think after the Test<T>::list the names inside Test<T> are in scope. Consider: `class A { class B {}; void c(B); }; void A::c(B) {}`

Comment: @bames: You're actually right (sorry if you read my earlier comment). [Case in point](http://ideone.com/C0ALx).

Comment: @bames53 bah, I deleted my comment about `SZ` needing qualification before looking it up in the standard. §9.4.2 [class.static.data] says "The initializer expression in the definition of a static data member is in the scope of its class (3.3.7)" but doesn't say anything about the declarator itself. Neither do I see anything under 8.4.2 [dcl.array]. So I think this might be a GCC bug.

Comment: @bames53: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062156/scope-of-evaluation-of-array-bound-of-static-data-member